# Webpack 4 Module Not Found

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I know there are many existing questions of the same title, but they seem to either not have any suitable answers or are relating to an older version of Webpack.

I am receiving the following error upon building (`webpack --mode development`):

> ERROR in ./scripts/eventSchedule.ts **Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve './Calendar'** in 'C:\Source Control\My Project\scripts'

The eventSchedule.ts file exists in the same folder as Calendar.ts and contains the following import statement:

```
import * as Scheduler from "./Calendar";
```

The Calendar.ts file contains an exported class and all of this **was working** prior to my upgrading from **Webpack 3 to Webpack 4**:

```
export class Calendar {
```

These are the contents of my webpack.config.js. What can I do to resolve this error?

Please note that while `wwwroot/dist/` is the output directory, nearly all of the scripts are located in `scripts`.

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'moment', 'fullcalendar'],
        modules: [
            './scripts/Calendar.ts'
        ],
        site: [
            './wwwroot/js/site.js',
            './scripts/onboardingFiles.ts',
            './scripts/eventFiles.ts',
            './scripts/allUsers.ts',
            './scripts/venueEquipment.ts',
            './scripts/audience.ts',
            './scripts/prerequisites.ts',
            './scripts/exportICS.ts',
            './scripts/eventSchedule.ts',
            './scripts/newHireTasks.ts',
            './scripts/upcomingEventsGrid.ts',
            './scripts/eventTypes.ts',
            './scripts/terminationTasks.ts'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    name: 'vendor',
                    test: 'vendor',
                    enforce: true
                },
            }
        },
        runtimeChunk: true
    }
};
```

Comment: You need a module rule to be able to read typescript files.

Comment: Comment the `optimization` config to make sure that isn't getting on the way. That is new to Webpack 4, so I'm pretty sure you didn't have it before your upgrade. Maybe you'll get a different error.

Comment: @givanse Commenting out the `optimization` block seems to have no effect on the error.  You're right, that block is new.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Were you using TypeScript before the upgrade? There is no loader for that in your config.

Comment: Yes, before I was using `ts-loader`.  I will try adding the loaders section as per https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/ and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with ts-loader
and looking in this
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1562#issuecomment-371545061

i noticed the following in the webpack.config.js file
and it worked for me

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"]
},
```

Comment: This was the solution I needed after a couple of hours of searching for errors with webpack, ts-loader and rxjs. Legend. I would upvote multiple times if I could.